# NetBackup with VSS and Instant Recovery - Failing to delete old snapshots

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, snapshot, netbackup, vss

We are attempting to implement Microsoft VSS for snap-shotting in our NetBackup 6.5.3.1 environment. The clients are both 32 & 64 bit Windows 2003 Server.

**Snapshot parameters are:**

- Instant recovery is enabled
- Maximum snapshots = 1
- Provider type = 1 (System)
- Snapshot attribute = 1 (Differential)

All backups successfully complete, and VSS shadows are successfully created both for the snapshot backup and for the open files (shadow copy components).

**The Issue:** 
NetBackup is not clearing or overwriting old snapshots with each successive backup. When we list shadows, and shadow storage, it is increasing and increasing. IT is not honouring the Maximum Snapshot setting.

**The Logs:**
The bpfis log doesn’t really appear to show any errors other than for methods which we are not employing (VxVM, Flashsnap, etc.). A section is as follows:

```
11:54:10.744 [348.4724] <2> logparams: D:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\bin\bpfis.exe delete -nbu -id htpststr001.san.mgmt.det_1248918143 -bpstart_to 300 -bpend_to 300 -clnt htpststr001.san.mgmt.det
11:54:10.744 [348.4724] <4> bpfis: INF - BACKUP START 348
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: VfMS error 10; see following messages:
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: Non-fatal method error was reported
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: vfm_configure_fi_one: method: FlashSnap, type: FIM, function: FlashSnap_init
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: VfMS method error 3; see following message:
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: FlashSnap_init: Veritas Volume Manager not installed.
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: VfMS error 10; see following messages:
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: Non-fatal method error was reported
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: vfm_configure_fi_one: method: vxvm, type: FIM, function: vxvm_init
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: VfMS method error 3; see following message:
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <8> onlfi_initialize_vfms: vxvm_init: Veritas Volume Manager not installed.
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <4> onlfi_thaw: Thawing C:\ using snapshot method VSS.
11:54:11.713 [348.4724] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: vfm_thaw: delete snapshot ...
11:54:11.744 [348.4724] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: snapshot services: emcclariionfi:Thu Jul 30 2009 11:54:11.744000 <Thread id - 4724> Unable to import any login credentials for any appliances.
11:54:11.760 [348.4724] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: snapshot services: hpevafi:Thu Jul 30 2009 11:54:11.760000 <Thread id - 4724> CHpEvaPlugin::init: CLI tool is not installed.
11:54:11.760 [348.4724] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: snapshot services: hpmsafi:Thu Jul 30 2009 11:54:11.760000 <Thread id - 4724> No array mangement credentials are available in configuration file.
11:54:13.806 [348.4724] <4> onlfi_thaw: do_thaw return value: 0
11:54:13.806 [348.4724] <4> onlfi_thaw: Thawing D:\ using snapshot method VSS.
11:54:15.806 [348.4724] <4> onlfi_thaw: do_thaw return value: 0
11:54:19.806 [348.4724] <2> fis_delete_id: removing D:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\online_util\fi_cntl\bpfis.fim.htpststr001.san.mgmt.det_1248918143.0
11:54:19.806 [348.4724] <2> fis_delete_id: removing D:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\online_util\fi_cntl\bpfis.fim.htpststr001.san.mgmt.det_1248918143.0.fiid
11:54:19.853 [348.4724] <4> bpfis: INF - EXIT STATUS 0: the requested operation was successfully completed
```

**The Question:**
Has anyone any experience of NetBackup / VSS not clearing snapshots after backups?

We will ultimately be using a HP EVA for the snapshots, but we want to ensure correct functioning at a VSS level before we go further.

Regards,

Jonathan

(PS: Question previously posted by my colleague on entsupport.symantec.com)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem using the VSP instead of the built in Microsoft VSS.  In the properties of the Master server -> Client Attributes, set the Snapshot Provider to "Use Microsoft Volume Shadow Copy Service..."
That fixed it for us, as the settings were then controlled by the client OS, not NetBackup.